The integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xt)}{t}dt$ using Laplace transforms
I want to show the following result using Laplace-transforms:
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xt)}{t}dt = \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align*}
My first thought was:
\begin{align}
& \mathcal{L}\{f(x)\} = \mathcal{L}\left\{ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xt)}{t}dt \right\} \\
& = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(xt)}{t}dtdx \\
& = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{t} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-sx}\sin(xt)dxdt\\
& = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{t} \mathcal{L}\left\{\sin(xt) \right\} \\
\end{align}
My question is: Does it matter if the variable in the exponent is $x$? That is, would the last step be correct if i had something like:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}\{f(x)\} = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{t} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-sy}\sin(xt)dydt
\end{align*}
If it does, why must they be the same?

Missing a $dt$ on the fourth line of the display, which might clarify which variable is a dummy variable of integration...

First, recall the definition of the Laplace transform of a function $f(t)$:
$$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s t} f(t) \, dt.$$
However, our integral doesn't include the exponential term. To bridge this, we'll use a property of Laplace transforms related to integrals of the form $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t} \, dt$. Specifically, this property connects the integral of $\frac{f(t)}{t}$ with the Laplace transform $F(s) = \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s)$:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t} \, dt = \int_{s}^{\infty} F(\sigma) \, d\sigma.$$
In our case, $f(t) = \sin(x t)$. The Laplace transform of $\sin(x t)$ is well-known:
$$\mathcal{L}\{\sin(x t)\}(s) = \frac{x}{s^2 + x^2}.$$
Therefore, $F(s) = \frac{x}{s^2 + x^2}$.
Using the property:
$$I(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x t)}{t} \, dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sigma^2 + x^2} \, d\sigma.$$
The integral simplifies to:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sigma^2 + x^2} \, d\sigma.$$
This is a standard integral that can be evaluated using the substitution $u = \frac{\sigma}{x}$:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sigma^2 + x^2} \, d\sigma = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u^2 + 1} \, du = \left. \arctan(u) \right|_{0}^{\infty} = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
The evaluation above assumes $x > 0$. To account for all real values of $x$, consider the following cases:

$x > 0$:

$$I(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

$x < 0$:

$$I(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x t)}{t} \, dt = -\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(|x| t)}{t} \, dt = -\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

$x = 0$:

$$I(0) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(0)}{t} \, dt = 0.$$
Combining the cases, the integral evaluates to:
$$\boxed{ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x t)}{t} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \text{sgn}(x) }$$

(+1) This is a correct evaluation https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5Bsin%5C%2840%29xt%5C%2841%29%2Ct%5D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D

Thanks, @keixx!

Suppose $x>0$. Using
$$ L\{1\}(t)=\frac1t, \int_0^\infty f(t)L\{g(s)\}(t)dt=\int_0^\infty L\{f(t)\}(s)g(s)ds$$
one has
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(xt)}{t}dt=\int_0^{\infty}\sin(xt)L\{1\}(t)dt=\int_0^{\infty}L\{\sin(xt)\}(s)ds=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{s^2+x^2}ds=\frac\pi2. $$
